# tkinter: dynamically create and delete entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am using tkinter to create a small GUI for some Python scripts. For this GUI I need a `Combobox` named `combo` with three options:

1. `"none"` (the user wants to hand in no data)
2. `"constant"` (the user wants to hand in only one value)
3. `"adjustable"` (the user wants to hand in more than one value)

Depending on the choice done in `combo`, a different number of entrys should
appear. The first option should show no entry (and delete all "leftover"
entrys), the second one should show only one entry and the third one should show
two entrys. For me it's no problem to create these entrys but I don't know how
to make them disappear. Once they were created they stay until the GUI is
closed.

I tried something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()

def submit():

    if choice.get() == "none": # all entry boxes schould disappear
        entry1.destroy()
        entry2.destroy()

    if choice.get() == "constant": # only 1 entry box schould be visible
        entry1 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = var1)
        entry1.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        entry2.destroy()

    if choice.get() == "adjustable": # all entry boxes should be visible
        entry1 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = var1)
        entry1.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

        entry2 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = var1)
        entry2.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

choice = tk.StringVar(value = "none")

combo = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable = choice, state = "readonly")
combo["values"] = ("none", "constant", "adjustable")
combo.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

action = tk.Button(master, text = "confirm", command = submit)
action.grid(column=1, row=0)

master.mainloop()
```

But as I said before, once a entry was created it did not disappear anymore. I
also tried `entry.grid_forget()` insted of `entry.destroy()` but this also
didn't work.

I also tryed to declare `entry1` and `entry1` outside of `submit()` but then I
don't know how to recreate these entrys once they were destroyed.

Comment: `entry1` and `entry2` are *local variables* within `submit()` - the moment the function exits, the variables are lost, and you have no further way to reference the widgets.  They need to have a longer lifetime - as global variables, perhaps.  You also need to deal with the possibility that one or both widgets haven't been created yet, in which case trying to destroy them won't work.

Comment: Yes. This was also on my mind but how do I check is the entry was already created or not?

Comment: Have the variables be `None` (or some other distinguishable value) whenever the corresponding widget does not exist.

Comment: Did you mean something like that:

Comment: `if entry1 != None:
                entry1.destroy()
                entry1 = tk.Variable()`

and  `entry = tk.Variable()` outside of `submit`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of jasonharper I found a solution while working at another script. The code should look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

master = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()

def submit():
    if choice.get() == "none": # all entry boxes schould disappear

        entry1.grid_remove()

        entry2.grid_remove()

    if choice.get() == "constant": # only 1 entry box schould be visible

        entry1.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

        entry2.grid_remove()

    if choice.get() == "adjustable": # all entry boxes should be visible

        entry1.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

        entry2.grid(column = 0, row = 2)


choice = tk.StringVar(value = "none")

combo = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable = choice, state = "readonly")
combo["values"] = ("none", "constant", "adjustable")
combo.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

entry1 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = var1)
entry2 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = var2)

action = tk.Button(master, text = "confirm", command = submit)
action.grid(column=1, row=0)

master.mainloop()
```

Now all entrys are deleted or created when wanted. To delete the text at the entrys You only have to add `entry.delete(0,"end")`.
I hope this will also help others.